# Self sorting table

Tags: excel-formula

## Situation

I am plotting 6 points on a graph that have to appear in sequence of their X coordinate.  4 of the X coordinates will always be in Ascending order.  2 of the X coordinates will appear anywhere and need to be positioned in the correct order.

### Six Points

1. left side of road
2. left wheel on road
3. left support
4. right support
5. right wheel
6. right side of road

## Calculating The Six Points

### Configuration Limitations

- The supports will always be under the road.
- The wheels currently may not even be on the road, straddle a support, be between supports, or both outside of the supports (same side or outside of both supports).
- The left wheel will always be equal to or less than the right wheel coordinate.  (setting wheel spacing = 0 is an option)
- The left side of the road will always be less than the left support
- The right side of the road will always be greater than the right support.
- There will always be a minimum of two supports with minimum spacing greater than 0

### User Inputs

- Support spacing `D2`
- Road width `D3`
- Centreline offset `D4`
- Left side extension `D5`
- Right side extension `D6`
- Axle spacing `D8`
- Right wheel distance from right edge `D9`

[image: User inputs]

```
Support spacing | 2.452 | m
Road width      | 4.268 | m
Centre offset   |     0 | m
Left extension  |     0 | m
Right extension | 0.305 | m

Axle spacing    |   1.8 | m
Right edge to   |     2 | m  
right wheel     |       |
```

#### Extra Extra Info

In the range D14:H15  I have some calculation that give coordinates that I am using to determine the Y values in the graph.  They may or may not be of use.  Row 14 is a measure of the length of the individual components and row 15 is the X coordinate of the right side of the component.  The columns have been labelled A through E and represent the following:

- A is the distance from the left side of the road to the left support
- B is the distance between supports
- C is the distance from the right support to the right side of the road
- D is the distance from the left side of the road to the left wheel
- E is the distance from the left side of the road to the right wheel

[image: Extra extra info]

```
   A   |    B   |    C   |    D   |    E
 0.908 |  2.452 |  1.213 |  0.773 |  2.573 
-1.226 |  1.226 |  2.439 | -1.361 |  0.439
```

### DATA Table

Currently I have the table organized by the component name. The next column the X coordinate is calculate based on the supports being centre about X=0.  The next column determines the X coordinate with the left side of the road equal to zero.  Essentially an offset of the previous column.  It is required for the calculations of the Y values.  Their calculation is already complicated enough without tossing in an X coordinat shift.

The next three columns are the Y values.  The first two Y values use similar formulas and are about 18 or so nested IF statements.  Since they have no bearing on how X is calculated I will mearly mention they are there.  I mention their length/complexity in case the formulas need to be placed inside another formula for sorting purposes, but I dont think that will be requires since their value is based off whatever ever the X values are, for the row they are in.

[image]

```
              |        |   X   |   F1  |    F2  | Total F
Left edge     | -2.134 |     0 |  0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00
Left support  | -1.226 | 0.908 | 23.65 |   0.00 |  23.63
Left wheel    | -1.361 | 0.773 |  0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00
Right support |  1.226 | 3.360 |  0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00
Right wheel   |  0.439 | 2.573 |  7.58 | -93.52 | -85.94
Right edge    |  2.439 | 4.573 |  0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00
```

The formulas inside C18 to C23 are pretty simple and are as follows:

```
=-D3/2-D5+D4
=-D2/2
=D3/2+D6+D4-D9-D8
=D2/2
=D3/2+D6+D4-D9
=D3/2+D6+D4
```

The above table winds up graphing as follows:

[image]

## What I have tried

What I have done in the past is to take the calculation for the wheel coordinate and compare it what ever row, and if it is less I display the wheel position otherwise I display the row position.  For B18 I would do something like:

```
=IF(D3/2+D6+D4-D9-D8<-D3/2-D5+D4,"Left Wheel","Left edge")
```

And since I have two wheels I am ok for checking B18 for just the wheel as it will always be before the right wheel.  however for B19 the check become a little more complex as the potential results are, Left Edge, Left Wheel, Right Wheel or Girder:

```
=IF(D3/2+D6+D4-D9<-D3/2-D5+D4,"Right wheel",IF(D3/2+D6+D4-D9-D8<-D3/2-D5+D4,"Left edge",IF(D3/2+D6+D4-D9-D8<-D2/2,"Left wheel","Left support")))
```

Now I would basically repeat that if statement going down modifying the If conditions and text for column B. I would then essentially copy it over to column C and replace the text results with the appropriate equations.

Since I am currently only dealing with 6 points, it is a manageable yet ugly solution.

## QUESTION

What I am wondering is if there is a better way to layout the data so it self sorts without manually using the built in sort function, nor VBA.  The table needs to wind up looking like:

[image]

Which will produce a graph that looks like:

[image]

### UPDATE

I just tried wrapping my head around the if statement for the third row and its really getting ugly.  To determine what the possible out comes were for each row, I wrote out each of the possible  configurations and wound up with 15 possible configurations.

[image]

ugh, I am now wrapping my head around if statement for row 3 and 6 different possible outcomes.  Its a little less manageable than I would have liked.

Comment: Holy crap, I thought your answers were long! You want me to read this?  Did you bring in lunch?

Comment: The background is long...the question is short.  I was hoping by providing close to as much detail as possible it MIGHT reduce the number clarification questions.  Dont ask how long it to me to write it or producing double tables in case people wanted to copy and paste.

Comment: Speaking of lunch, I think it may be a good time to go grab some since I started this question a couple of hours ago when it WAS the lunch hour.  Give you time to read after all 8)

Comment: @ScottCraner Saddly when I add updates to show any progress I have made, it makes the question longer not shorter.

Comment: is it a bad sign when there are more characters in your question than there are character in your entire spreadsheet (including formulas)?

Comment: I have been wracking my brain and can't figure out a method that does what you want without vba.  You may consider that.  Load the values into an array then sort the array and past the values back.  You can tie it to the worksheet change or calculate event so it updates as values update.

Comment: @ScottCraner I think I just had an epiphany? I am getting frustrated trying to read `D3/2+D6+D4-D9<-D3/2-D5+D4`.  So it just hit me to use named formula.  So I could make `RIGHT_WHEEL` = `D3/2+D6+D4-D9` and `LEFT_EDGE` = `D3/2-D5+D4` so now the comparison reads `=if(RIGHT_WHEEL<LEFT_EDGE, TRUE result, FALSE result).  That in itself is not the big news but does make the if statements so much easier to read.  What brought that on was I should have a table that actually has all the coordinates list rather than burying them in hidden places.

Comment: @ScottCraner As soon as I have that table, I can turn around and simply use a `LARGE` function with an `INDEX/MATCH` for names, and the Y values will sort themselves since they are based on whatever the X value is.  Though admittedly I was hoping to avoid another table but I see merit in this particular table.

Comment: You are basically doing what I suggest in vba.  Creating a second table is similar to creating an array then sorting and putting it back.  It is the only way I see it happening.  It is a good Idea.

Comment: Welll the IF method would work but as stated, ugly.  What I am really liking about this table option is if I ever added more supports, you just expand the table and it takes care of itself.  The IF route...not so robust.  FYI this is a BASIC analysis of a bridge deck on two girder.  Most HWY bridges are multi-girder systems.  I just tend to be dealing with small logging road bridges.

Comment: @findwindow  too many screen shots right? 8)

Comment: No, not enough screen shots or enough words.

Comment: @findwindow and here I thought a picture was worth a thousand words!

Comment: So you build roads?

Comment: @findwindow Actually no, I design bridges...which support/link roads

Comment: Oh groovy. That's a lot of math XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after eating some lunch and then trying to start in on the if statements, and apparently essentially following the VBA suggestion by Scott Craner for sorting, I had an epiphany.

My solution to this was to essentially create a table of important coordinates:

[image]

Then to generate my table that I use for graphing and associated Y values, I used the following for my X coordinates:

```
=SMALL($C$18:$C$23,ROW()-ROW($C$30))
```

Which displays the coordinates in ascending order, with the ROW()-ROW($C$30) acting as a counter.

To display the associated name to the X value I used a combination INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($B$18:$B$23,MATCH($C31,$C$18:$C$23,0))
```

No adjustment was required to the 4 other columns of my table.  The advantage of this method is it allows me to easily add supports under the road in future if there was a need without having to mess around with a series of IF statements.